# awk: if pattern is found, count lines until the first empty line

Tags: regex, awk

In a large document, once a pattern is found, count all the lines, from the next line of the pattern, until the first empty one:

```
...
PATTERN 
BBBB
CCCC

...
```

It should print: 2

What I have tried:

```
awk '/PATTERN/{print $0}' file | wc-l
```

Comment: What is pattern and what did you try?

Comment: @anubhava thank you, post clarified

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -v p='PATTERN' '$0 ~ p{n=NR} n && !NF{print NR-n-1; exit}' file

2
```

- When we find a pattern set a variable `n` as current line number i.e. `NR`
- When we find next empty line we print the difference